# Recursive formula does not work as intended

Tags: recursion, programming

For my cs class Ive been given the following task. I have n different beers, and the i'th beer has a price of p[i]. the prices are: p1 = 2, p[2] = 3, p[3] = 2, p[4] = 1, p[5] = 4. I also have c coins, and I wish to figure out how many ways I can spend all the money on beers, with n = 5, and c = 5.

I know that there are 4 possible ways I can spend the money, (p1,p[2]), (p1,p[3],p[4]), (p[2],p[3]), (p[4],p[5]).

The task is to write a recursive formula, for the number of ways I can spend all my c money.

For now, I have this recursive formula:
N(C,i) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if C $<$ 0 or i $<$ 0 }\\
1 &\text{if C = 0}\\
N(C,i-1)+N(C-p_i,i) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

The formula basically calls itself repeatedly until either c=0, where it returns 1 (as it has exactly spend all its money), or if c < 0 or I < 0, it returns 0 as it has spend more money than it has, and therefor isn't valid.

But I'm not sure if it's correct. I tried writing the formula as code, but it returns 11 when it should return 4.

```
def fn(c,i):
    if(c < 0 or i < 0):
        return 0
    if(c == 0):
        return 1
    return fn(c,i-1)+fn(c-p[i-1],i)
```

I could really use some help, if someone can see if my recursion formula is wrong, or my code is wrong.

I hope I haven given the necessary information, or else I gladly answer all questions.

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  What exactly does $N(C,i)$ denote?  I assume there is only one bottle of beer of each type, no?  So...if my first purchase was $p_i$, I can't buy bottle $i$ again so why am I still looking at $i$ options?

Comment: I see i have typed c both in uppercase and lowercase, which probably causes some confusing.. N(C, i) is the recursive formula, where C is the amount of coins in hand, and i is the i'th beer. So if i = 3, it has a price of p[3] = 2. You can't by the same beer multiple times, so (p[4],p[4],p[4],p[4],p[4]) is not allowed. I see your last point though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost your version, however, this yields the correct answer for your test case (assuming zero indexing for the function input).

```
def rec(c, i):
  global p
  if c == 0:
    return 1
  if i < 0 and c != 0:
    return 0
  return rec(c, i - 1) + rec(c - p[i], i - 1)
```

Do you see your mistake?

Comment: I see, looks like it I forgot to extract 1 from I at both of them. makes sense thanks!

Comment: "global" is unnecessary here

Comment: @MatthewTowers true, slightly confused the meaning of it here